# Перенос баз данных на примонтированный раздел

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

После какого-то момента родного раздела базам стало мало, был добавлен еще один, но после переноса стартовать мускуль отказывается. Версия БД MSQL 5.6.27.

Что и в каком порядке делал:

1) стопарю mysql

2) монтирую во временную папку новый раздел и копирую на него все из /var/lib/mysql/

3) удаляю(или переименовываю, и то и то пробовал) все из /var/lib/mysql/

4) размонтирую раздел из временной папки и монтирую его в /var/lib/mysql

```
umount /dev/sdb
mount /dev/sdb /var/lib/mysq/
```

5) в файл /etc/fstab добавляю

```
/dev/sdb /var/lib/mysql ext4 defaults 0 0
```

6) добавляю права

```
chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/ -R
chmod 755 /var/lib/mysql
```

7) пытаюсь стартануть мускуль или перезагрузить систему, и... ошибка

Немного истории и логов:

```
director@Zabbix-VCSTO:~$ sudo ls -l /var/lib/mysql
total 176160
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql       56 нояб. 28 10:02 auto.cnf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root         0 нояб. 28 10:00 debian-5.6.flag
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 79691776 февр.  6 09:54 ibdata1
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 50331648 февр.  6 09:54 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 50331648 февр.  6 09:54 ib_logfile1
drwx------ 2 mysql root      4096 нояб. 28 10:02 mysql
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql     4096 нояб. 28 10:02 performance_schema
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql    12288 нояб. 28 10:41 zabbix
```

Error log:

```
160206 09:17:40 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2016-02-06 09:17:40 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2016-02-06 09:17:40 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.27-0ubuntu1) starting as process 11591 ...
2016-02-06 09:17:40 11591 [Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)

2016-02-06 09:17:40 11591 [Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)

2016-02-06 09:17:40 11591 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2016-02-06 09:17:40 11591 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2016-02-06 09:17:40 11591 [ERROR] Function 'innodb' already exists
2016-02-06 09:17:40 11591 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'innodb' with soname 'ha_innodb.so'.
2016-02-06 09:17:40 11591 [ERROR] Function 'federated' already exists
2016-02-06 09:17:40 11591 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'federated' with soname 'ha_federated.so'.
2016-02-06 09:17:40 11591 [ERROR] Function 'blackhole' already exists
2016-02-06 09:17:40 11591 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'blackhole' with soname 'ha_blackhole.so'.
2016-02-06 09:17:40 11591 [ERROR] Function 'archive' already exists
2016-02-06 09:17:40 11591 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'archive' with soname 'ha_archive.so'.
2016-02-06 09:17:40 11591 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-02-06 09:17:40 11591 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-02-06 09:17:40 11591 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2016-02-06 09:17:40 11591 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-02-06 09:17:40 11591 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2016-02-06 09:17:40 11591 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2016-02-06 09:17:40 11591 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-02-06 09:17:40 11591 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2016-02-06 09:17:40 11591 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-02-06 09:17:40 11591 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-02-06 09:17:40 11591 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 161408190289
2016-02-06 09:17:40 11591 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2016-02-06 09:17:40 11591 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2016-02-06 09:17:40 11591 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2016-02-06 09:17:40 11591 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2016-02-06 09:17:40 11591 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 161413432832
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 161416161894
2016-02-06 09:17:40 11591 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 06:17:40 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 76296 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x3b)[0x8dbb4b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x37b)[0x63c7bb]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10d10)[0x7f019cb83d10]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x9488c9]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x94a4f5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x932004]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x9339d3]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa081c9]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa4bef6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x9ab518]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76aa)[0x7f019cb7a6aa]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f019c00eeed]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
160206 09:17:40 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
160206 09:27:40 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2016-02-06 09:27:40 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2016-02-06 09:27:40 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.27-0ubuntu1) starting as process 13941 ...
2016-02-06 09:27:40 13941 [Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)

2016-02-06 09:27:40 13941 [Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)

2016-02-06 09:27:40 13941 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2016-02-06 09:27:40 13941 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2016-02-06 09:27:40 13941 [ERROR] Function 'innodb' already exists
2016-02-06 09:27:40 13941 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'innodb' with soname 'ha_innodb.so'.
2016-02-06 09:27:40 13941 [ERROR] Function 'federated' already exists
2016-02-06 09:27:40 13941 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'federated' with soname 'ha_federated.so'.
2016-02-06 09:27:40 13941 [ERROR] Function 'blackhole' already exists
2016-02-06 09:27:40 13941 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'blackhole' with soname 'ha_blackhole.so'.
2016-02-06 09:27:40 13941 [ERROR] Function 'archive' already exists
2016-02-06 09:27:40 13941 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'archive' with soname 'ha_archive.so'.
2016-02-06 09:27:40 13941 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-02-06 09:27:40 13941 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-02-06 09:27:40 13941 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2016-02-06 09:27:40 13941 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-02-06 09:27:40 13941 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2016-02-06 09:27:40 13941 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2016-02-06 09:27:40 13941 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-02-06 09:27:40 13941 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2016-02-06 09:27:40 13941 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-02-06 09:27:40 13941 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-02-06 09:27:40 13941 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 161408190289
2016-02-06 09:27:40 13941 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2016-02-06 09:27:40 13941 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2016-02-06 09:27:40 13941 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2016-02-06 09:27:40 13941 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2016-02-06 09:27:40 13941 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 161413432832
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 161416161894
2016-02-06 09:27:41 13941 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 06:27:41 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 76296 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x3b)[0x8dbb4b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x37b)[0x63c7bb]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10d10)[0x7fbe80c9fd10]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x9488c9]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x94a4f5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x932004]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x9339d3]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa081c9]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa4bef6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x9ab518]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76aa)[0x7fbe80c966aa]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7fbe8012aeed]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
160206 09:27:41 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
160206 09:37:41 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2016-02-06 09:37:41 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2016-02-06 09:37:41 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.27-0ubuntu1) starting as process 16321 ...
2016-02-06 09:37:41 16321 [Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)

2016-02-06 09:37:41 16321 [Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)

2016-02-06 09:37:41 16321 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2016-02-06 09:37:41 16321 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2016-02-06 09:37:41 16321 [ERROR] Function 'innodb' already exists
2016-02-06 09:37:41 16321 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'innodb' with soname 'ha_innodb.so'.
2016-02-06 09:37:41 16321 [ERROR] Function 'federated' already exists
2016-02-06 09:37:41 16321 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'federated' with soname 'ha_federated.so'.
2016-02-06 09:37:41 16321 [ERROR] Function 'blackhole' already exists
2016-02-06 09:37:41 16321 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'blackhole' with soname 'ha_blackhole.so'.
2016-02-06 09:37:41 16321 [ERROR] Function 'archive' already exists
2016-02-06 09:37:41 16321 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'archive' with soname 'ha_archive.so'.
2016-02-06 09:37:41 16321 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-02-06 09:37:41 16321 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-02-06 09:37:41 16321 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2016-02-06 09:37:41 16321 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-02-06 09:37:41 16321 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2016-02-06 09:37:41 16321 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2016-02-06 09:37:41 16321 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-02-06 09:37:41 16321 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2016-02-06 09:37:41 16321 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-02-06 09:37:41 16321 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-02-06 09:37:41 16321 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 161408190289
2016-02-06 09:37:41 16321 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2016-02-06 09:37:41 16321 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2016-02-06 09:37:41 16321 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2016-02-06 09:37:41 16321 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2016-02-06 09:37:41 16321 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 161413432832
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 161416161894
2016-02-06 09:37:41 16321 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 06:37:41 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 76296 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x3b)[0x8dbb4b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x37b)[0x63c7bb]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10d10)[0x7f73cf481d10]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x9488c9]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x94a4f5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x932004]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x9339d3]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa081c9]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa4bef6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x9ab518]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76aa)[0x7f73cf4786aa]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f73ce90ceed]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
160206 09:37:41 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Подскажите в какую сторону копать или более красивый вариант переноса.

Comment: 1. в пункте два вы скопировали что-то не то, а в третьем пункте зачем-то уничтожили нескопированную информацию. бэкапы-то есть? 2. никаких *chown*-ов и *chmod*-ов выполнять не надо (и даже вредно). если вы копировали нормально, с опцией `-a`.

Comment: 1. на смонтированный в левую папку раздел копирую базы из var/lib/mysql/ . Уже исправил в тексте, опечатался. Конечно есть, что интересно, они успешно привиты таким точно способом другой виртуальной машине.
2. нет, копировал без параметров. Сейчас попробую

Comment: @AmoyakAkopyn Если вы делали chown, то почему у вас /var/lib/mysql/mysql имеет группу "root" ? там внутри небось еще и файлы непонятно с каким пользователем. А теперь главный вопрос - вы файлы копировали при остановленном mysql ? У вас он крашиться вообще SIGSEGV при попытке накатить redo из логов. У меня ощущение, что у вас logfile'ы не соответствуют данным (idbdata)

Comment: И почему у вас в каталоге нет ни одного mysql-bin файла. один должен быть по идее, если конечно логи innoDB на корню не выключены

Comment: @mike

director@Zabbix-VCSTO:~$ sudo dir /var/lib/mysql
auto.cnf         ibdata1      ib_logfile1  performance_schema
debian-5.6.flag  ib_logfile0  mysql        zabbix

вывод с рабочего сервера
да. все копируется при выключенном сервере. права к файлам не применились бо я дубина, забыл ключ -R

Comment: @AmoyakAkopyn И после восстановления прав починилось или нет ?Если нет - то вам надо выполнять http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html  И скорее всего задирать innodb_force_recovery сильно. Если придется так делать, то сразу после старта базы надо выгружать все данные и пересоздавать базы, потому как возможны повреждения в файле данных. И перед этим где нибудь копии ваших файлов еще сохраните

Comment: @mike нет, права на всех вложенных файлах mysql mysql. все равно не стартанул. сейчас буду читать мануал что вы прислали.

Comment: Можете в гугле вбить innodb_force_recovery там еще статьи на эту тему будут.

Answer (score 1):

Восстанавливать базы не пришлось. После недельного шаманства, все получилось как я описал выше, но до этого переносил(при выключенном сервере, конечно) базы из основного раздела на вторичный, потом обратно. Менял права, обновлял базы `mysql_upgrade -u root -p`лез в `/run/mysqld/` удалял все оттуда(если было) и перестартовал базу. Сейчас все прекрасно работает. Всем спасибо за отклик!
[image: результат]